# My sqlite database in db form not working on actual device but work fine in simulator

Tags: ios, database, sqlite

In my app I am doing read ,write and delete on sqlite database(in db form) and it work fine in simulator but not working in actual device (giving error: `No such table found`).I try very hard to look for solution but couldn't find one or may be i misread something.

My db is in the

> /users/My Name/library/developer/Core
>   simulator/devices/devicen-id/data/application/app-id/documents/My
>   database.

```
- (NSString *) getWritableDBPath {

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
return [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:mydaatabase];

}
```

I am confuse where did i need to copy my database while running in the actual iOS device and what is the core problem.Any help regarding this will be very helpful

```
-(void)createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded
{

BOOL success;
NSFileManager *fileManager1 = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:mydaatabase];
NSLog(@"=======%@", writableDBPath);

success = [fileManager1 fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];
if (success)
    return;

NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]
                          stringByAppendingPathComponent:mydaatabase];
NSLog(@"=======%@", [NSBundle mainBundle]);

success = [fileManager1 copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath
                               toPath:writableDBPath
                                error:&error];


if(!success)
{
    NSAssert1(0,@"Failed to create writable database file with Message : '%@'.", 
    [error localizedDescription]);
}
}
```

Comment: Can you check if fileExists at "defaultDBPath" ?

Comment: @almas- i checked at the document its there but  i don't understand what du you mean by default path and how to check it ,thanks for the responds

Comment: "defaultDBPath" is the original place where you copying your database from, it is in your code that you provided. Just verify that the file actually exists before you even try to copy it to the documents folder.

Comment: i had put the database in document folder as shown in the above file and check it and it is there,Its working fine in simulator but not in actual device -@almas

Comment: NSString * mydaatabase=@"tibetananddetail.db";
NSString * mydaatabaseforfav=@"favorite.db";    NSString * paths=[self getWritableDBPath];                                                             const char *dbpath =  [paths UTF8String];   this is my opening code for the database---@Rumin

Comment: Does your `.sqlite` file exist in `Copy Bundle Resources` in `Build Phases` of your project?

Comment: i checked in Bundel resources ,its not there do i need to copy it here also and is it ok to copy it manually--@Rumin

Comment: It should be there in `Bundle  Resources`. Add your database file in `Bundle Resources`.

Comment: i had added the database file to the bundle resources and  it still not working.I did it manually and check it twice--@Rumin

Comment: Wait I am posting the answer below..

Comment: @TenzinJinpa check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your `.sqlite` file is added to your `Copy Bundle Resources` in `Build Phases` of your project. If it is not there, add it in your project.

Moreover, I can't find code for opening the database. So, in your `ViewController.h` file, declare `Sqlite *database;`

In your `ViewController.m` file,

```
-(void)databaseOpen

{
    NSArray *paths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory=[paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *myDBnew=[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourSqliteFile.sqlite"];

    database =[[Sqlite alloc]init];
    [database open:myDBnew];
    NSLog(@"path: %@", myDBnew);

    NSLog(@"Database opened");

}
```

and call it wherever you want as `[self databaseOpen];` and then write your query.

Also, your `-(void)createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded` should look something like this in your `AppDelegate.m`:

```
- (void)createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded
{
    // First, test for existence.
    BOOL success;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourSqliteFile.sqlite"];
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];
    if (success) return;

    // The writable database does not exist, so copy the default to the appropriate location.

    NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourSqliteFile.sqlite"];
    success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error];
    if (!success) {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
    }


}
```

Call `-(void)createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    [self createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded];
    return YES;
}
```

This should get you going.

Comment: @Rumin-- thanks for the answer, in my  Bundle Resources  i had a copy of my database.db but not the mydatabase.sqlite file so do i need to copy the .sqlite file also

Comment: Yes... you need `.sqlite` and not `.db` file. `.db` is your database and it would be fetched automatically once you add `.sqlite` file.

Comment: i had tried this one also but didn't work...i can't understand why is it working on simulator fine not in the actual device--@Rumin

Comment: Did you change your code to the above one? I recommend you to do all the things that I have mentioned above. Also delete the app once and run it again.

Comment: yap its working now thanks for the help and especially Rumin...your was the correct solution and help me a lot thank you once again

Comment: @TenzinJinpa Please do the needful. It helps keeping the stackoverflow clean and other users will find this helpful if they come across such  a problem. Please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: @Rumin-sorry for late checked and thanks once  again.

Answer (score 0):

Here are steps to working with SQLite Database.

1. Create your database in SQLite, add required table with well structure. and add it to your application.
2. Now, go to your app, select project from left panel, in middle panel -> General -> Linked Frameworks and Libraries(Last one) add `libsqlite3.0.tbd` (it is depend upon your Xcode version.)
3. Now, define below methods in `your-object.h`

   ```
   #import <sqlite3.h>

   + (NSString *)getDBPath;
   + (void)copyDatabaseIfNeeded;
   + (void)openDatase;
   ```
4. Implement these in  `your-object.m`

   ```
   static sqlite3 *database;

   #pragma mark - Copy and open databse

   + (NSString *)getDBPath
   {
       NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
       NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
       return [documentsDir stirngByAppendingPathComponent:@"dbName.sqlite"];
   }

   + (void)copyDatabaseIfNeeded
   {
       NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
       NSError *error;

       NSString *dbPath = [self getDBPath];
       BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];

       if(!success)
       {
           NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"dbName.sqlite"];
           success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:dbPath error:&error];

           if (!success)
               NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
       }
   }

   + (void)openDatase
   {
       NSString *dbPath = [self getDBPath];

       if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
       {
           NSLog(@"Database Successfully Opened.");
       }
       else
       {
           NSLog(@"Error in opening database.");
       }
   }
   ```
5. Then call method in `AppDelegate.m` in `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

   ```
   [DataManager copyDatabaseIfNeeded];
   ```
6. Whenever you want to perform task with database, open it and check.

For inserting in database

```
     + (void)insertData
     {
         const char *dbpath = [[self getDBPath] UTF8String];

         if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
         {
             NSString *strSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO table name………………."];
             const char *insertQuery = [strSQL UTF8String];
             sqlite3_stmt *insert_stmt;

             if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insertQuery, -1, &insert_stmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
             {
                 if (sqlite3_step(insert_stmt) == SQLITE_DONE)
                 {
                    // Code
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     NSLog(@"error");
                 }
             }
             sqlite3_finalize(insert_stmt);
             sqlite3_close(database);
        }
    }
```

7. Completed.... enjoy with database.