# Adding record to table in SQLIte file won't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I'm trying to add record to SQLite file but nothing happens. I get no error and in console I get that record is inserted in table `@"----> RECORD INSERTED"`. Below you can see the code that I'm using. Please, can someone tell me how to fix this. Thanks for your time and help.

```
- (void)addRecordToSQLiteDatabase
{
   BOOL success;
   NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
   NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
   NSString *appDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ProductiivData.sqlite"];
   success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:appDBPath];

   if (success) 
   {
       const char *databaseCharPath = [appDBPath UTF8String];
       if (sqlite3_open(databaseCharPath, &(database)) == SQLITE_OK)
       {
           char *errorInsert;
           const char *insertRecordInPROJECT = "insert into PROJECT values (139, 'TEST1888799')";

           if (sqlite3_exec(database, insertRecordInPROJECT, NULL, NULL, &errorInsert))
           {
               NSLog(@"----> RECORD INSERTED");
           }
           else
           {
               NSLog(@"----> RECORD NOT INSERTED -- Error: %s", errorInsert);
           }

           char *errorSelectAll;
           sqlite3_stmt *statement = NULL;
           const char *allRecordsFromPROJECT = "select * from PROJECT";

           if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, allRecordsFromPROJECT, 1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
           {
                while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
                {
                    NSString *projectName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
                }
           }
           else
           {
                NSLog(@"----> RECORDS NOT SELECTED -- Error: %s", errorSelectAll);
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Write `if (sqlite3_exec(database, insertRecordInPROJECT, NULL, NULL, &errorInsert) == SQLITE_OK)` and check what is the output now you are getting

Comment: Refer this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33294747/my-sqlite-database-in-db-form-not-working-on-actual-device-but-work-fine-in-simu/33295220#33295220

Comment: Yes I just add that... Now I get the error: "no such table: PROJECT". But I'm positive that my table is PROJECT and that exists in SQLIte file. Because I opened it with another application and I can see the table.

Comment: @mattkoder: Are you sure that the database and table name is correct ?

Comment: You are not reporting `sqlite_open()` failures.

Comment: @mattkoder: Print `appDBPath` and check whether the db file at that path contains the table. Probably you added the table later and the file at that folder may not contain the latest change.

Comment: This is the path: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/5D8B6003-4FBA-449E-9187-D46EF5015908/Documents/ProductiivData.sqlite

Comment: @mattkoder: Open the sqlite file contained in that folder and check whether it has the table named `PROJECT`

Comment: @MidhunMP: Yes, it's there...

Answer (score 0):

Separate insert and select logic, Try following code

Get Database path

```
+ (NSString *)getDBPath
{
     NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
     NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
     NSString *dbPath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"dbName.sqlite"];

     NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
     NSError *error;

     BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];

     if(!success)
     {
         NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"dbName.sqlite"];
         success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:dbPath error:&error];

         if (!success)
             NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    return dbPath;
}
```

Insert Data

```
+ (void)insertData
 {
     const char *dbpath = [[self getDBPath] UTF8String];

     if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
     {
         NSString *strSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO tableName………………."];
         const char *insertQuery = [strSQL UTF8String];
         sqlite3_stmt *insert_stmt;

         if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insertQuery, -1, &insert_stmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
         {
             if (sqlite3_step(insert_stmt) == SQLITE_DONE)
             {
                // Code
             }
             else
             {
                 NSLog(@"error");
             }
         }
         sqlite3_finalize(insert_stmt);
         sqlite3_close(database);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Error in opening database.");
    }
}
```

Get data from table

```
+ (NSArray *)getDataList
{
    NSMutableArray *arrProducts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    const char *dbpath = [[self getDBPath] UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *strSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM tableName"];
        const char *selectQuery = [strSQL UTF8String];
        sqlite3_stmt *select_stmt;

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, selectQuery, -1, &select_stmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            while(sqlite3_step(select_stmt) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                NSInteger productID = sqlite3_column_int(select_stmt, 0);
                NSString productNo = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(select_stmt, 1)];
                // Store above data into dictionary or object and then add this to array
                [arrProducts addObject:dict];
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Error in opening database.");
    }
    return arrProducts;
}
```

Comment: Please summarise what's changed.  It's difficult to run `diff` on a web browser.

Comment: It won't work... if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insertQuery, -1, &insert_stmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) won't pass this line of code.

Comment: Have you get any error, then please show your error

Comment: I tried updated code of yours... But still won't pass this line of code: if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insertQuery, -1, &insert_stmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK). It won't get into if statement. And I get no error.

Comment: @mattkoder So the `sqlite3_open()` is failing and you are not reporting an error?

Comment: if (success) {
        const char *databaseCharPath = [appDBPath UTF8String];
        if (sqlite3_open(databaseCharPath, &(database)) == SQLITE_OK) {

in this code "success" is true. And if with sqlite3_open returns SQLITE_OK and it enters in if statement. Because of that I think that connection is OK. And I don't get any error.

Comment: That's because you aren't reporting any error.  Why "think" and not "know"?